# Eigen C++ Library gives error with C++ 11 option

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen3

I have the following C++ code where I used Eigen C++ Library.

```
#include "Dense"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXf x(10,10);
    x.setRandom();
    std::cout<<"x is ..\n"<<x<<std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

When I try g++ with "-std=gnu++11" it gives the following error.

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:55,
                 from ../SP_ToolBox/ExternalLibraries/Eigen/Eigen/Core:153,
                 from ../SP_ToolBox/ExternalLibraries/Eigen/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from test.cpp:1:
../SP_ToolBox/ExternalLibraries/Eigen/Eigen/array:8:4: error: #error The Eigen/Array header does no longer exist in Eigen3. All that functionality has moved to Eigen/Core.
   #error The Eigen/Array header does no longer exist in Eigen3. All that functionality has moved to Eigen/Core.
    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:55:0,
                 from ../SP_ToolBox/ExternalLibraries/Eigen/Eigen/Core:153,
                 from ../SP_ToolBox/ExternalLibraries/Eigen/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:885:33: error: ‘array’ was not declared in this scope
     struct __is_tuple_like_impl<array<_Tp, _Nm>> : true_type
                                 ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:885:44: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
     struct __is_tuple_like_impl<array<_Tp, _Nm>> : true_type
                                            ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:873:12: error: provided for ‘template<class> struct std::__is_tuple_like_impl’
     struct __is_tuple_like_impl : false_type
            ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:885:47: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ token
     struct __is_tuple_like_impl<array<_Tp, _Nm>> : true_type
```

It compiles fine if I remove "-std=gnu++11" option.
My gcc version is 4.8.4 and Eigen Library version is 3.2.10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you have put the Eigen include directory directly on the header file search path. That means when the *standard* `<array>` header file is included, the compiler will actually include the Eigen `array` header file instead.

Change your `-I` flag to not include the full path, only up to e.g. `../SP_ToolBox/ExternalLibraries/Eigen` (i.e. drop the last `/Eigen`).

Then include `<Eigen/Dense>` instead.